# javascript parent of parent

Tags: javascript, parent

In javascript is there an easy way to target the parent of a parent?

I'm using `this.parentNode` as the element of a function to select the parent, and I tried both `this.parent.parentNode` and `this.parentNode.parentNode`, but both simply return the direct parent.
I'm trying to affect the div surrounding the div surrounding the 'this'. I did manage to make it work using a simple loop statement that repeats the parentNode selection twice, but I assume there's a better way.

Comment: `this.parentNode.parentNode` should work just fine. I see no reason why it shouldn't.

Comment: `this.parentNode.parentNode` should work.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`this.parentNode.parentNode` is correct, you must (with apologies!) have had a mistake in the test where you tried it.

Example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ivozib/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ivozib/1/edit)

HTML:

```
<div id="outermost">Outermost
  <div id="inner1">Inner 1
    <div id="inner2">Inner 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var inner2 = document.getElementById("inner2");

display("inner2.id = " + inner2.id);
display("inner2.parentNode.id = " + inner2.parentNode.id);
display("inner2.parentNode.parentNode.id = " + inner2.parentNode.parentNode.id);

display("Try clicking the blue 'inner2' above");

inner2.onclick = function(e) {
  display("Click: this.id = " + this.id);
  if (this.parentNode) {
    display("Click: this.parentNode.id = " + this.parentNode.id);
    if (this.parentNode.parentNode) {
      display("Click: this.parentNode.parentNode.id = " + this.parentNode.parentNode.id);
    }
  }
};

function display(msg) {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = String(msg);
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

Output (assuming one clicks as directed):

```
inner2.id = inner2
inner2.parentNode.id = inner1
inner2.parentNode.parentNode.id = outermost
Try clicking the blue 'inner2' above
Click: e.target.id = inner2
Click: e.target.parentNode.id = inner1
Click: e.target.parentNode.parentNode.id = outermost
```

Comment: @user2126833: No worries. Did this sort it out, or are you still seeing a problem in your real code? If so, you might want to post a new question giving the full context (markup and code) and folks will be happy to help. For instance, could it be that it only *seemed* to give you the same parent? For instance, if you have a `div` inside a `div` inside a `div`, all three levels will be `div` elements, so it would be easy to think that `.parentNode` and `.parentNode.parentNode` both gave you the same element...

Comment: thank you your answer was very helpful . there should be a definitive guide to parse all HTML elements whether dynamic or static, it's really confusing collecting all this information from here and there.